# "System.NullReferenceException" using EF.Property while querying a database EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

community. I'm trying to query a database using spatial data and PostgreSQL. I use NetTopologySuite. So far so good. Now, my model does not use the NetTopologySuitePoint class which has a method called DistanceTo which is translated in the database. So, in ModelCreating, I map this property and add a conversion to-from Point. Everything is fine here, I can query the database using SQL commands, but, now, I need to do it with EntityFrameworkCore, using LINQ.

To convert I use:

```cs
builder.Entity<Address>(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("Addresses");
                x.Property(b => b.Coordinates).HasConversion(
                    v => new Point(v.Latitude, v.Longitude),
                    v => new Protos.Coordinates { Latitude = (float)v.X, Longitude = (float)v.Y });
            });
```

When I want to query:

```cs
await mRepository.AsQueryable<Business>()
      .Include(x => x.TradeBranchs).ThenInclude(x => x.Address)
      .Where(x => x.Category == category)
      .Where(x => x.TradeBranchs.Any(b => EF.Property<Point>(b.Address, nameof(Address.Coordinates)).Distance(customerPoint) <= (distance / 1.609)))
      .PaginateAsync(currentPage, pageSize);
```

Here I use **EF.Property<NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point>(b.Address, nameof(Address.Coordinates))** because how I said previously, i couldn't use **Distance** with my own Coordinates class.

but I don't know why the following exception is thrown:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlGeometryMethodTranslator.TranslateGeometryMethod(SqlExpression instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments
 at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlGeometryMethodTranslator.Translate(SqlExpression instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Translate>b__3(IMethodCallTranslator t
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext(
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider.Translate(IModel model, SqlExpression instance, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.Internal.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCall
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression
 at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.Internal.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression
 at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.Internal.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateInternal(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateExpression(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateLambdaExpression(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression, LambdaExpression lambdaExpression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateWhere(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression predicate
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateAny(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression predicate
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSubquery(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Query.Internal.NpgsqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCall
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateInternal(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateExpression(Expression expression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateLambdaExpression(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression, LambdaExpression lambdaExpression
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateWhere(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression predicate
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression
 at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor
 at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken
 at Reddi.Backend.Manager.UserManager.GetBusinessesAsync(Address customerAddress, Double distance, BusinessCategory category, Int32 pageSize, Int32 currentPage) in /workspace/src/reddi/Backend/master/Reddi.Backend.Master/Manager/UserManager.cs:line 814
```

It seems like somewhere its null, but where?

Comment: looks like a problem with querying .Include(x => x.TradeBranchs).ThenInclude(x => x.Address). I think the problem is this line.

Comment: @AVTUNEY what do you think about that? Foreign keys problem?